# How to convert SVM optimization problem into terms of quadratic programming?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm reading "The Elements of Statistical Learning", to be precise chapter about optimal separating hyperplanes (SVM classification problem) and I've stuck with the following.
I have a function to be maximized:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_ia_ky_iy_kx_i^Tx_k,
$$

subject to:

$$
0 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_ia_i, \quad b = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_iy_ix_i, \quad a_i \ge 0 \quad \forall{i}, \quad a_i[y_i(x_i^Tb + b_o) - 1] = 0 \quad \forall{i}
$$

where $y$ and $x$ are known variables and $a$, $b$ and $b_0$ should be found.

And as far as I understand the next step should be to solve this problem using any of quadratic programming approach. In the same time quadratic programming problems looks like:

$$
\frac{1}{2}X^TQX+C^TX
$$

subject to:

$$
Ax \le B
$$

And I don't understand **how to convert the first problem into the second**. As far as I see we can transform $a_i \ge 0$ can be transformed into $Ax \le B$, but what about $a_i[y_i(x_i^Tb + b_o) - 1] = 0$? It looks like a quadratic constraint and cannot be transformed into linear constraint.

Comment: Can you clarify which symbols are fixed and which variables are to be optimized over? For example, I assume we don't get to choose the variables $a_i$?

Comment: I've updated the question. Variables $x$ and $y$ are known, other variables should be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an optimization problem with the following constraints
$$
a_i[y_i(x_i^Tb+b_0)-1] \geq 0 \quad \forall 1 \leq i \leq N.
$$
But using Kuhn-Tucker's theorem, you formed an equivalent dual problem, that can be solved via quadratic programming. And in this problem the specified condition is redundant. All you need is complementary slackness and non-negativity conditions:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N a_i y_i \geq 0 \text{ and } a_i \geq 0 \ \forall 1 \leq i \leq N.
$$